# How to get info from website and display it as message with Discord bot?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, webpage-screenshot

So I have this site https://spsknm.edupage.org/substitution/ and I want to display the part "Chýbajúci učitelia: ..." in Discord with a bot. I managed to scrape all the HTML from that URL but I can't find that specific string there. It's probably because they use some kind of script to display it.

The second idea I came up with was to screenshot that URL through some Node.js package, save it to Github and then display it in Discord as attachment. But this doesn't work too.

```
const captureWebsite = require('capture-website');
(async () => {await captureWebsite.file('https://spsknm.edupage.org/substitution/', 'suplovanie.png');})();
const suplovanie = new Attachment("./suplovanie.png");
msg.channel.send(suplovanie);
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put all in an `async` function. For example:

```
(async () => {
    const captureWebsite = require('capture-website');
    await captureWebsite.file('https://spsknm.edupage.org/substitution/', 'suplovanie.png');})();
    const suplovanie = new Attachment("./suplovanie.png");
    msg.channel.send(suplovanie);
})();
```

Now, it will wait for the capture, and then send the message.